# Link not working as popup in html email

Tags: html, outlook

Really simple here but i am trying to generate a link within an email that popups a page but its not working it also is througing a security exception in outlook 365 how does one properly open a popup from email with correct height and width of window.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://apertureiva.com/opt-out'">here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using scripts is totally unsupported in emails.

"Scripting in Emails
The short answer is that scripting is unsupported in emails. This is hardly surprising, given the obvious security risks involved with a script running inside an application that has all that personal information stored in it.

Webmail clients are mostly running the interface in JavaScript and are not keen on your email interfering with that, and desktop client filters often consider JavaScript to be an indicator of spam or phishing emails.

Even in the cases where it might run, there really is little benefit to scripting in emails. Keep your emails as straight HTML and CSS, and avoid the hassle."

Source: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/

You can use target="_blank" instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer one other thing i notice is that when i do copy and paste from the web browser to outlook it replacing the reference with the path of html file anyway around that

Comment: How do you mean that? Do you copy the url from the address bar or do you copy the actual html source?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the a tag this way:

```
<a href="https://apertureiva.com/opt-out" target="popup" onclick="window.open('https://apertureiva.com/opt-out','name','width=800,height=600')">Open page in new window</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thats works without throwing the security aleart but does not let me resize the window ?